# How to populate UserInfo object in DNN Authentication providers?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, dotnetnuke

I am trying to create an authentication provider in DotNetNuke 7.4 which supports LinkedId. I have used the source package for the Facebook provider from the DnnPlatform GIT as the base and have modified it for LinkedIn's oAuth. I am able to connect via LinkedIn and get the auth token but the code fails on

```
 OAuthClient.GetCurrentUser<LinkedInUserData>();
```

due to LinkedInUserData being null. the specific logged error is

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - ~/Default.aspx?tabid=55&error=An unexpected error has occurred
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthClientBase.GetCurrentUser[TUserData]()
   at DotNetNuke.Authentication.LinkedIn.Login.GetCurrentUser() in c:\Websites\dnndev74_2\DesktopModules\AuthenticationServices\LinkedIn\Login.ascx.cs:line 103
```

Below are the 3 classes that are in play, there is a lot of inheritance going on so I'm having trouble understanding the mechanism for how LinkedInUserData gets populated in the first place. On a note. when I take the facebook codebase from GIT and install it as a provider on my local, and try to register with facebook account, I get the same error. However, if I install the provider through the CMS it runs fine or use the dll that comes with the dnn 7.4 install, facebook works. So I am lead to believe there is something fundamentally flawed with the GIT code..

LinkedInClient.cs

```
    namespace DotNetNuke.Authentication.LinkedIn.Components
{
    public class LinkedInClient : OAuthClientBase
    {
        #region Constructors

        public LinkedInClient(int portalId, AuthMode mode) 
            : base(portalId, mode, "LinkedIn")
        {
            base.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization");
            base.RequestTokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_emailaddress");
            base.TokenMethod = HttpMethod.POST;
            base.TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken");
            base.MeGraphEndpoint = new Uri("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,formatted-name,picture-url)?format=json");
            base.AuthTokenName = "LinkedInUserToken";
            base.OAuthVersion = "2.0";
            base.LoadTokenCookie(string.Empty);
        }

        #endregion

        protected override TimeSpan GetExpiry(string responseText)
        {
            var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var tokenDictionary = jsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(responseText) as Dictionary<string, object>;

            return new TimeSpan(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(tokenDictionary["expires_in"]));
        }

        protected override string GetToken(string responseText)
        {
            var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var tokenDictionary = jsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(responseText) as Dictionary<string, object>;
            return Convert.ToString(tokenDictionary["access_token"]);
        }
    }
}
```

LinkedInUserData.cs

```
namespace DotNetNuke.Authentication.LinkedIn.Components
{
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class LinkedInUserData : UserData
    {
        #region Overrides

        public override string FirstName
        {
            get { return LinkedInFirstName; }
            set { }
        }

        public override string LastName
        {
            get { return LinkedInLastName; }
            set { }
        }

        public override string Email
        {
            get { return emailAddress; }
            set { }
        }

        public override string ProfileImage
        {
            get { return LinkedInPictureUrl; }
            set { }
        }

        #endregion

        [DataMember(Name = "first-name")]
        public string LinkedInFirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "last-name")]
        public string LinkedInLastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "picture-url")]
        public string LinkedInPictureUrl { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "email-address")]
        public string emailAddress { set; get; }

}
```

Login.cs

```
namespace DotNetNuke.Authentication.LinkedIn
{
    public partial class Login : OAuthLoginBase
    {
        protected override string AuthSystemApplicationName
        {
            get { return "LinkedIn"; }
        }

        public override bool SupportsRegistration
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        protected override UserData GetCurrentUser()
        {
            return OAuthClient.GetCurrentUser<LinkedInUserData>();
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            loginButton.Click += loginButton_Click;
            registerButton.Click += loginButton_Click;

            OAuthClient = new LinkedInClient(PortalId, Mode);

            loginItem.Visible = (Mode == AuthMode.Login);
            registerItem.Visible = (Mode == AuthMode.Register);
        }

        protected override void AddCustomProperties(NameValueCollection properties)
        {
            base.AddCustomProperties(properties);

            properties.Add("LinkedIn", OAuthClient.GetCurrentUser<LinkedInUserData>().Link.ToString());
        }

        private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AuthorisationResult result = OAuthClient.Authorize();
            if (result == AuthorisationResult.Denied)
            {
                UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage(this, Localization.GetString("PrivateConfirmationMessage", Localization.SharedResourceFile), ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.YellowWarning);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

I wrote a DNN provider for Linkedin a couple years ago.  Comparing my code to yours, the first thing mine does is redirect the user in order to get an access token.  The base url for obtaining the access token and permission from the user is: www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2.  I must pass my linked API key, a redirect Url and a few other pieces of data which comes from the provider settings.

My redirect Url is the same as the default portal login page which loads my provider. Once the user allows LinkedIn to allow my application access and verifies he is logged in, the redirect back to my provider will look for the LinkedInAuthToken cookie in the Request.Cookies. Once I verify the token is valid, I can make an additional API call to the /v1/people/ API to get user data to complete any kind of auto-registration or auto profile updates to DNN.

It seems like your provider is immediately attempting the user data lookup API call before obtaining the oauth access cookie.

The code for my LinkedIn provider is not open source, but I suppose I could get permission from my work to make it public.  Message me if you are interested in it.